# Linkedin Javascript Profile API broken

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

Few days ago Linkedin Javascript Profile API stopped work as normal. Now it not returning some fields, even if i requested for them. I can't get summary, awwards, positions company name sumary and title. Can enyone tell what is happening?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  scope: r_basicprofile r_emailaddress r_fullprofile r_contactinfo
  authorize: true
</script>

function loadData() {
  IN.API.Profile("me")
    .fields([
"id","summary","email-address","location:(name)","date-of-birth","firstName", "lastName", 
"pictureUrl","headline","honors","educations","interests",
"publications:(title,publisher:(name),date,url)",
"patents:(title,number,office:(name),date,url)",
"languages:(language:(name),proficiency:(name))",
"skills:(skill:(name),proficiency:(name))",
"certifications:(name,authority:(name),start-date,end-date)",
"courses","recommendations-received:(recommendation-text,recommender)",
"positions","phone-numbers"])
    .result(function(result) {   
        console.log(result);
    });
}
```

Here is working example of this bug http://bit.ly/1nZa9wd  You can see, that even if i request for summary info it not returned in response.

Comment: Your example URL is returning fields such as positions for me (which you said you couldn't retrieve). Can't verify summary or awards as my profile doesn't have them.

Comment: positions does not return any info except dates and company id. And this problem concern only javascript API. REST API with oauth2 access token working fine.

Comment: Amol, can you give an example where it working normal?

Answer (score 0):

Some data cannot be retrieved via API. See this talk here: https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/connections-api-does-not-return-all-profile-fields-documented.

It is already documented in the API here: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields

The exact quote from the Notes field is `Not available via connections API.`

Comment: i'm not retrieving connections, i need user profile. And as for profile it use this url api:
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people::(~):(id,summary,email-address,location:(name),date-of-birth,first-name,last-name)

Comment: And also time of the post is Jul 20, 2011, and i'm started to getting error only week ago. Before this day all was working ok.